# Django2 and Angular2 url integration problem with parameters

Tags: django, angular, url, integration

I have an url with parameters.

Angular tries to make a call to it but django waits and slash after the url and angular adds a question mark before the parameters.

How can I integrate both?

Django url:

```
path("data/a=<str:a>&b=<str:b>&c=<str:c>/", views.DataView.as_view({'get': 'get'}))
```

Angular:

```
let options = Object.assign({}, this.options);
let params = new URLSearchParams();

params.set('a', vehicle);
params.set('b', from); 
params.set('c', until);

options['search'] = params; 

let url = "https://miweb.com/data/";

return this._http.get(url,options).map
    (res =>res.json());
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include how you currently have the url configured in Django and in Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using GET params in angular, you should remove the GET parameters from path, as well as the as_view call (unless you really need it for some other reason):

```
path("data/", views.DataView)
```

And then in your view, use the request object to access the GET parameters if they exist:

```
def DataView(request):
    # check for GET parameters
    param_vehicle = request.GET.get('a')

    param_from = request.GET.get('b')

    param_until = request.GET.get('c')

    if None in (param_vehicle, param_from, param_until):
        # Handle missing inputs as necessary

    # Validate parameters here

    # rest of view goes here
```